# Apache - Serving static files from different subdomain + machine

Tags: apache-2.2, static-files

Here's the scenario

A site is running on this domain - **www.someserver.com**

I'm going to host **subdomain.someserver.com** on my machine.

Let's say all the image files are under the directory '**img**'.

I don't want to copy all their images to my machine. So what should be the Apache directive(s) that'll map the request for an image, like

http://subdomain.someserver.com/img/image.png

to

http://www.someserver.com/img/image.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On subdomain.someserver.com:

```
Redirect /img http://www.someserver.com/img
```

On www.someserver.com:

```
AliasMatch (.*)$ /location/of/home/directory/$1
```